# how to get a return recipt from mailutils?

Tags: command-line, mail

In gmail, and other mail clients, it is possible to tell if an email has been opened using something called a return receipt. (If there is another term please, do tell). Is there any such functionality in the mailutils command line program? If so, how can I use it?

Answer (score 1):

It's basically a flag in the message that requests the client of the reader to return a receipt. Most clients will by default ask the user before sending the receipt, so it's by no means a guarantee that you'll get a receipt.

The request is sent as a e-mail header. With mailutils you can't change the headers of a mail you're sending. I would suggest that you use `mutt` instead. It's a bit more sophisticated than mail - and mutt is mutt on every platform, whilst mail differs a lot from platform to platform. Mutt can, of course, send with arbitrary headers.

From mutt's man page:

> -H draft
>   Specify a draft file which contains header and body  to  use  to send a message.

This can obviously be used to insert arbitrary headers into an e-mail. The file (or stdin) `draft` should be on the following format:

```
From: example@example.org
To: example@example.com
Return-Receipt-To: myself@example.org
Subject: Please confirm when you've read t    From: example@example.org
To: example@example.com
Return-Receipt-To: myself@example.org
Subject: Please confirm when you've read this!

This is the body of the message.
```

This can of course be sent via stdin, by running `<some command to generate the e-mail> | mutt -H -`

In addition to the `Return-Receipt-To:` header you may try other headers like `X-Confirm-Reading-To:` or `Disposition-Notification-To:`.