# Mail in Command Line Interface

Tags: command-line, mail, mailutils

How can I know if my mail is delivered when I used Command line to send it? I used the MailUtile package.

Comment: For myself mail is usually delivered in a few seconds. It's when mail **is not** delivered (usually due to a bad address) that I get a message and that is usually within a minute.

Answer (score 0):

Mails don’t generally return a “delivered” value after they’re sent. However, you can add a flag to request for a read-receipt once the destination address owner you’re sending the mail to has opened it. There are 2 scenarios you’ll be getting feedback here:

1. If the destination address is incorrect, typically mail servers will send a message back to the sender stating so.
2. If the destination owner has opened the mail, and the mail was set to include a read-receipt return address, a message will be auto-generated and sent back to the address you specify under ‘Return-Receipt-To’. There is a pretty good and complete explanation here: [how to get a return recipt from mailutils?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/964947/how-to-get-a-return-recipt-from-mailutils)

NOTE: Read-receipts can be denied by the receiving party, in which case the sender will not get a read-receipt back.